# Multiple syntax value shorther

Tags: vb.net

This code I think could be made shorter, from a maximum of one line of code or two. Do you think it's possible? I am a beginner user and do not know how to do this shorter.

```
    Dim Numbers() As String = Split(TextBox1.Text, ",")
    Dim Num1 = Numbers(0)
    Dim Num2 = Numbers(1)
    Dim Num3 = Numbers(2)
    Dim Num4 = Numbers(3)
    Dim Num5 = Numbers(4)
    Dim Num6 = Numbers(5)
    Dim Num7 = Numbers(6)
    Dim Num8 = Numbers(7)
    Dim Num9 = Numbers(8)
    Dim Num10 = Numbers(9)
    Dim Num11 = Numbers(10)
    Dim Num12 = Numbers(11)
    Dim Num13 = Numbers(12)
    Dim Num14 = Numbers(13)
    Dim Num15 = Numbers(14)
    Dim Num16 = Numbers(15)
    Dim Num17 = Numbers(16)
    Dim Num18 = Numbers(17)
    Dim Num19 = Numbers(18)
    Dim Num20 = Numbers(19)
    Dim N1 As String = Num1, N2 = Num2, N3 = Num3, N4 = Num4, N5 = Num5, N6 = Num6, N7 = Num7, N8 = Num8, N9 = Num9, N10 = Num10, N11 = Num11, N12 = Num12, N13 = Num13, N14 = Num14, N15 = Num15, N16 = Num16, N17 = Num17, N18 = Num18, N19 = Num19, N20 = Num20
```

Comment: The code does not actually do much, it splits a string, all the other lines do basically nothing since you are not using the variables so it's impossible to know how this could be made clearer/shorter. Anyway use a loop to loop through the items, don't use indexes. What if there are only 19 items? Or more than 20? Also there is https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ which is more suited for this question.

Comment: Is there a specific reason why you want to avoid using the `Numbers` array?

Comment: You have 3 different variables, all with the same value. Why? Numbers(0) is the same as Num1 and the same as N1. Which is strange because they are not numbers; they are strings.

Comment: To shorten the code, stop after the first line.